# Python getting an error of bool is not callable on a function when it was used the second time in a loop

Tags: python, foreign-keys, cursor, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a foreign key between tables that has been uploaded into the cloud:

This is the script based on:

1. Adding the main table
2. Alter main table to have a primary key named (_INDEX)
3. Connect the main table to the top level table through primary key named as (SURVEY_ID)
4. Add the child table
5. Connect the child table to the main table through _PARENT_INDEX from it into _INDEX from the main table.

Step 3 is working between main table and top level table, but the same function executed at step 5 is resulting an error of:

> 'bool' object is not callable

Here is the script:

```
add_dataframe = add_dataframe_as_table(conn, cursor, data, survey_new_title)
if(add_dataframe==True):
    add_foreign_key = add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, 'SURVEYS', survey_new_title, 'SURVEY_ID', 'SURVEY_ID')
# Specify _INDEX as a primary key so it can be used as foreign key in the child table
add_primary_key = add_primary_key_for_main_survey(conn, cursor, survey_new_title, '_INDEX')
```

This script is working properly with no error. Here is `add_dataframe_as_table()`, `add_foreign_key()` and `add_primary_key_for_main_survey()` scripts:

Adding dataframe as table:

```
def add_dataframe_as_table(conn, cursor, df, survey_title):
    try:
        print("Number of rows: "+str(len(df)))
        start_time = time.time()
        data.to_sql(name=survey_title, 
              con=engine.connect(), 
              if_exists="replace", 
              # dtype=object,
              index=False)
        print(survey_title+' to_sql() done.'+'---\n', file=logfile)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)+'---\n', file=logfile)
        print(survey_title+' to_sql() done.'+'---\n')
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)+'---\n')
        return True
        # log_frame.append({'Survey Name': filename, 'Survey ID': nextval}, ignore_index=True)
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error) as e:
        print("******* Error adding the table: "+ str(e)+'*******\n', file=logfile)
        print("******* Error adding the table: "+ str(e)+'*******\n')
        conn.rollback()
        return False
```

Connect main table to `SURVEYS` table through foreign key (working good here):

```
def add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, reference_table_name, child_table_name, child_table_key_name, reference_table_key_name):
    print('Add_Foreign_Key')
    try:
        print('--- Adding a foreign key between the child table: '+child_table_name+ ' and the reference table: '+reference_table_name+' with foreign key as: '+child_table_key_name+' ---\n')
        print('--- Adding a foreign key between the child table: '+child_table_name+ ' and the reference table: '+reference_table_name+' with foreign key as: '+child_table_key_name+' ---\n', file=logfile
             )
        child_table = "\""+database+"\".\""+schema+"\".\""+child_table_name+"\""
        print(child_table)
        query = """ALTER TABLE {0} ADD FOREIGN KEY ({1}) REFERENCES {2}({3})"""\
            .format(child_table.replace('\'', '\'\''), child_table_key_name, reference_table_name, reference_table_key_name)
        print("Foreign Key Query: "+query+"\n")
        print("Foreign Key Query: "+query+"\n", file=logfile)
        if(cursor.execute(query)):
            print("--- "+child_table+ " FOREIGN KEY added successfully"+" ---\n")
            print("--- "+child_table+ " FOREIGN KEY added successfully"+" ---\n", file=logfile)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error) as e:
        print("******* Error when adding foreign key: "+ str(e)+" *******\n")
        print("******* Error when adding foreign key: "+ str(e)+" *******\n", file=logfile)
        return False
```

Specifying primary key of main table so it can be used as foreign key in the child table:

```
def add_primary_key_for_main_survey(conn, cursor, main_table, main_column):
    print('------- Adding a primary key for: '+main_table+' ---\n')
    print('------- Adding a primary key for: '+main_table+' ---\n', file=logfile)
    try:
        main_table = "\""+database+"\".\""+schema+"\".\""+main_table+"\""
        query = """ALTER TABLE {0} ADD PRIMARY KEY ({1})""".format(main_table.replace('\'', '\'\''), main_column);
        if(cursor.execute(query)):
            print('------- Primary key: '+main_column+' has been successfully added to the table: '+main_table+' ---\n')
            print('------- Primary key: '+main_column+' has been successfully added to the table: '+main_table+' ---\n', file=logfile)
            return True
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error) as e:
        print('******* Error on adding primary key: '+str(e)+' *******\n')
        print('******* Error on adding primary key: '+str(e)+' *******\n', file=logfile)
        conn.rollback()
        return False
```

Now on the child table side:

```
add_dataframe = add_dataframe_as_table(conn, cursor, data, survey_new_title)
print(main_survey, survey_new_title) # printing correct names
# Getting the error in here
add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, main_survey, survey_new_title, '_PARENT_INDEX', '_INDEX')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write:

```
add_foreign_key = add_foreign_key(conn, cursor, 'SURVEYS', survey_new_title, 'SURVEY_ID', 'SURVEY_ID')
```

Then you erase your function `add_foreign_key` with its result that is a bool. So further call to this raise the exception.